# Proving that $S_n$ and $A_n \times A_n$ are not isomorphic for $n \geq 5$ sanity check.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

My proof was: $|S_n| = n! \neq n!/2 \cdot n!/2 = |A_n \times A_n|$ for $n \geq 5$, so the groups are not isomorphic.

But you can get 15 points for this question, whereas you get only 7 for proving that there is no simple group of order 2015, which is much more difficult. Is my proof wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the question meant $A_n \times C_2$ ?

Comment: Lol sanity check should be a tag.

Comment: 15 points from where? Can you show us where the problem comes from? It may be a typo.

Comment: Your professor will announce tomorrow morning that there was a mistake on the exam.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. What's the doubt? And it is correct for every $n>1$.

Comment: It's just deceptively easy for a question that is marked as difficult, so I thought I may have overlooked something. Thanks for putting my mind at ease.